# Saving GUI data from matlab in a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I'd like to save matrices which are input via GUI pushbuttons in a 3D matrix. for example: I click button 1 a 2-2 matrix is put in the first slice of the 3D matrix. I than click button 3 and a different 2-2 matrix is put in the second slice. SO on and so on. I hope this is clear enough. The problem I have is that I'm not an experienced programmer. I currently initialize a zeros matrix as follows in the opening func:

```
storageMatrix  = ones(2,2,100);
setappdata(0, 'storageMatrix', storageMatrix);
```

I have put a function `updateStorageMatrix` in the main script like this, mind you this isn't finished yet.

```
function updateStorageMatrix

storageMatrix = getappdata(0, 'storageMatrix');
```

and than when I look at my code of pushbutton 1 for example it looks like this:

```
% --- Executes on button press in Add_Straightduct.
function Add_Straightduct_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%prompt command for k number and length
    prompt       = {'k0:','Length:'};
    dlg_title    = 'Straight Duct specs';
    num_lines    = 1;
    SDelements   = {'0','0'};
    Straightduct = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,SDelements)

%insert values in function
    sizeStorageMatrix = size(getappdata(0,'storageMatrix'));      %get size of the storage matrix

    dimT              = sizeStorageMatrix(1,3);   %take the number of matrices

        if dimT==1

            straightDuct = straight_duct(str2num(SDelements{1}), str2num(SDelements{2}), Mach_Frange(1,1))

            setappdata(handles.updateStorageMatrix,'storageMatrix', storageMatrix(1:2, 1:2, 1))=straight_duct(str2num(SDelements{1}), str2num(answer{2}), Mach_Frange(1,1))

            dimT+1

        else 
            setappdata(0,'storageMatrix', storageMatrix(1:2, 1:2, dimT+1))=straight_duct(str2num(SDelements{1}), str2num(answer{2}), Mach_Frange(1,1))
            dimT+1
        end
```

the `straight_duct()` is a function I used in the script when calculating the mufflers, I have several of those functions, I am not sure if that's the way to work when using GUI. I just hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve and help me on my way. So I can actually make a UI for my script :)

Comment: Consider using `handles.storageMatrix = zeros(2,2,100);` and make sure to call `guidata(hObject,handles)` to save the change to the `handles` struct before leaving the callback function an element was added to the struct. Maybe someone else could shed some light on whether this or the `setappdata()` method is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you've initialized the storageMatrix elsewhere in the GUI like this...

```
handles.storageMatrix = zeros(2,2,100);
guidata(hObject,handles); % Must call this to save handles so other callbacks can access the new element "storageMatrix"
```

Then in your first button's callback...

```
% --- Executes on button press in Add_Straightduct.
function Add_Straightduct_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
.
. % Whatever initializations you need to do
.

localStorageMatrix = handles.storageMatrix;  %load the storageMatrix being used by other callbacks/functions

.
. % Whatever you need to do to generate the new 2x2 matrix "slice"
.

localStorageMatrix(:,:,end+1) = newSlice; % appends the new slice to the end of the, indexing using colons assumes newSlice is of the same first and second dimension as other slices in localStorageMatrix
handles.storageMatrix = localStorageMatrix; % overwrite the storageMatrix in handles with the contents of the new localStorageMatrix
guidata(hObject,handles); % save the handles struct again now that you've changed it
```

Alternatively, you could have just used the `handles.storageMatrix` throughout, without including a `localStorageMatrix` but I've included it for emphasis.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! i will try it tomorrow. I was really at a dead end looking for someone to explain it to me :)

Comment: this actually showed me how to use the handles. correctly! it's been of great use. Cheers.